# Difference between past simple and present perfect

Tags: tense, difference, present-perfect, past-simple

How are these two sentences different in meaning?

> 1) She looks very familiar; I **have seen** her somewhere before.
>
> 2) She looks very familiar; I **saw** her somewhere before.